# How to create mobile only website

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, web, mobile-website

I have presently using bootstrap to make a responsive website. But problem is that, in this case we need to load all the same content for mobile as well which is not required, like heavy images, text etc. which are good only for desktop websites. So, I thought of creating a mobile version of this website which based on User-agent will open.

But I am confused with technology stack to make such website. I need to give users view as well as features which are available in native app. So user coming from mobile do not feel odd using our website. I have found two libraries for such purpose (jquery mobile and angular mobile ui)

I am impressed by mobile view of following website:

1. zivame.com
2. cilory.com

For these two websites I fail to understand what library they are using to deliver such smooth and native view and functionality. Please suggest me which tools or libraries should I use to make such beautiful website like zivame.com ?

Comment: Have you tried to inspect page source of these websites? It would contain references to CSS and javascript libraries they use.

Comment: Yes tried but found jquery and scriptalacious's js files